# Ensure GLSL compatibility

Tags: c++, opengl, compatibility, glsl, shader

How can ensure that GLSL shaders are compatible with most modern cards?

I've got a software where I use GLSL code from [here](http://mouaif.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/photoshop-math-with-glsl-shaders/). But even though I've added #version 120 to the beginning of my final shader and made sure it compiles, on some users computers they get shader compilation errors (even though they support OpenGL 3.2).

Is there any tool I can use to "validate" or try compiling with different "shader compilers"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no tool for validating a shader. Even if there was, it wouldn't be useful to you, because what good is a shader that is "valid" if it doesn't run on the hardware you want? You can be right all you want, but if your hardware rejects it even though you're technically right, your shader still won't run.

If a shader of a particular version compiles on one target (call it A) and not on another (call it B), this could be due to one of the following problems:

1. Target A does not properly implement GLSL. It allowed you to compile something that the spec does not allow. The more compliant target B (or at least, differently non-compliant) rejects your shader, because your shader does not follow the specification.
2. Target B is non-compliant with the specification. You are feeding it a legitimate shader and it is rejecting it.
3. Target B does not support the version of GLSL your shader uses (this is unlikely), except when:
4. Target B is using the OpenGL core specification, version 3.2 or greater. GLSL 1.20 shaders cannot be run on core 3.2 OpenGL implementations.

#1 is more likely to happen if you develop solely on NVIDIA hardware. NVIDIA plays a bit fast-and-loose with the OpenGL specification. They will take a few liberties here and there, smoothing out some of the unpleasant things the specification says. It makes for a smoother developer experience, but it also helps with keeping vendors using NVIDIA hardware if shaders don't run on competitors ;)

#3 is pretty much non-existent, with the noted exception. You linked to a Photoshop shader, so I gather that you are not in control of the creation and management of the OpenGL context. Even so, I highly doubt Photoshop would use a core context; they have too many shaders that need backwards compatibility.

The best way to deal with this is to test on both AMD and NVIDIA hardware (and Intel if you need to run there). You may not need to test on every possible combination of systems, but pick a Radeon HD card and a GeForce 200 or better. They don't even have to be high-end.

Comment: I'm developing on NVIDIA cards. Is there any software compiler which can simulate ATI shader compilation?

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that all the hardware vendors write their own implementations of the GLSL compiler in their drivers. Even though the language is defined quite well, this leads to inconsistencies in shader parsing. For instance, the Nvidia drivers often "forgive" certain small mistakes, which are caught by ATI's.

A reasonable solution, I think, is to use Nvidia's Cg instead (http://developer.nvidia.com/cg-toolkit) - this way you will make your shaders hardware-agnostic and make sure they run on all hardware.

Comment: I fail to see how using Cg helps. Cg can be compiled to GLSL, but it's _NVIDIA's_ compiler doing the compilation. I see no reason to expect NVIDIA's Cg compiler to produce GLSL that is any more likely to be "hardware-agnostic" than just writing GLSL directly. NVIDIA likes to talk about Cg being cross-platform, but it's not.

Comment: From your post I'm not sure you really understand how Cg works. It does not produce GLSL that is hardware-agnostic - it compiles (or "translates" would probably be a more appropriate word here) Cg code at runtime to a form which applies best to the hardware it's running on. The agnosticity lies in hardware detection and pipeline choice at runtime.


Do you have any personal experiences with Cg producing GLSL that doesn't compile on ATI? I do have experience with it producing code that just works, on NVIDIA, ATI and Intel. There's a reason why major players such as Epic, DICE and others use it.

Comment: I do know that the "hardware detection and pipeline choice at runtime" are all under the control of NVIDIA, since they write the compiler for it. And I do know that Epic and DICE are both "The Way It's Meant to Be Played" partners of NVIDIA. So you're not exactly convincing me that Cg is a good thing outside of the NVIDIA-ecosystem. I simply doubt that NVIDIA has compiler engineers who go through each AMD driver release and adjust the compiled result to match any driver irregularities.

Comment: So by that you accept to take the task of going through every AMD driver release upon yourself. This is not a viable option for many programmers. Cg, on the other hand, takes a substantial workload off the coder's back without a large performance penalty and provides very reasonable results with regard to the aforementioned hardware agnosticity.

On a side note, ATI/AMD has somewhat of a tradition of poor OpenGL support, which I personally perceive as the root of this and loads of other related problems.

Comment: Well, I don't trust NVIDIA to do it. And I seriously doubt Epic and DICE do either; they test their Cg shaders on AMD hardware just like every other major game developer. And NVIDIA has a tradition of loose OpenGL support, where they accept things outside of the specification. Which is _actually_ the root of Ronag's problem. Bugs are bugs, whether it's accepting more input than the spec says or accepting less. If I write a GLSL shader that works on AMD, it is a lot more likely to work without modifications on NVIDIA than vice-versa.